# vagrant/ansible wrong version of nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, vagrant

Having Vagrantfile:

```
...
    Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
      config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
      config.vm.box_url = "https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise64"
      config.vm.hostname = vm_hostname
      config.vm.boot_timeout = 720
...
```

Trying to insall nginx with *.yml:

```
- name: Install Nginx
  become: yes
  apt: pkg=nginx state=latest
```

In a result having VM, typing "nginx -v" gives "1.1.19" which is extremely outdated (ppa:ngins/stable as of date have 1.12 as a stable)

Please help to install latest version of nginx )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a pretty old box (I would even say deprecated as hashicorp has rebuilt the boxes as [ubuntu/precise64](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/precise64) - the box you're using has not been updated for 3 years (check https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise64))

so you can try with

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/precise64"
```

but note ubuntu 12.04 is quite old as ubuntu release, you should look to use a more recent version, you can use

- ubuntu/trusty64 : its ubuntu 14.04
- ubuntu/xenial64 : its ubuntu 16.04 (this box had some issues in the past, not sure everything was fixed)

Comment: Thanks!) Went with a same solution hour before))) took xenial64, and all works